# Best way to close the socket and streams

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

In eclipse in one of the classes SonarLint and sonarqube server saying socket is not closed, even I closed it.

FYR:
[image]

What is the best way to close the socket? Could anyone please guide me.

Note: I don't get this error if I don't have out = new ObjectOutputStream(...)  code in the same try block.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-with-resources Statement something like:

```
            try (ObjectOutputStream out =
                           new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()) {
               .....
            }
```

Comment: go thru below link to see how to use try with resource statement                            https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

```
    try (Socket socket=new Socket(ipAddress, port);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
           //this is how you can use socket & out
        out.write(null);
        socket.getInetAddress();
    }
```